# PHP will not echo JSON_ENCODE unless i echo something else

Tags: php, json

i have a file on the disk that i retrieve, and store its contents into an array for display as json.

```
function getCurrentPic($username, $password){
  $con = connectToPDO();
  $valid = validateUser($username, $password);
  if($valid == 1){
    $sth = $con->prepare('
      SELECT current_pic
      FROM user 
      WHERE 
      username = :username');
    $sth->execute(array(':username' => $username));
    $sth->bindColumn(1, $imagePath, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
    echo spitImageJSON($imagePath);
  }
}


function spitImageJSON($imagePath){
  if(strlen($imagePath) > 1){
    $IDPath = $imagePath.'d';
    $id = getContentsAtPath($IDPath);
    $image = getContentsAtPath($imagePath);
    //echo "$imagePath";
    $arrayData = array(array(
      'image' => $image,
      'id' => $id
      ));
    return json_encode($arrayData);
  }
}
```

that code doesn't work unless i uncomment the echo "$imagePath", at which point it prints the path AND the json.. when i re-comment it, nothing is echoed. I'm losing my mind. please help.

btw the file is just a base64 encoded string.. id is just a numerical string

Comment: Can you show us how you call your functions?

Comment: Then `json_encode()` produces something invisible (possibly `FALSE`).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario idk how because when i uncomment the echo, it echoes the json just fine with no false anywhere in the keys or values.. UPDATE: i put a random echo into the function while echo "$imagePath" was commented out and that didn't even print. it only displays things on my screen if that line is not commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by placing

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

before returning the json, it worked like it was supposed to without the echo $imagePath

Comment: Changing the content-type shouldn't affect how the data was being returned. `json_encode` returns a plain text string that will be visible under any content-type.

Comment: @David thats what i thought, but it works now so i'll just let it stick

Comment: I agree with David. I strongly suspects that "nothing is echoed" means "some JavaScript code that processes the script output at a later stage does not emit output".

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario there's no javascript or html. this is the server side of an iOS app, i viewed the output in a web browser though. the file is literally: 1)incoming $_GET 2)execute those methods 3) echo it

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, I had to add the following on top over the correct answer:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```